# Set padding at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, margin, padding, textview

My Question:
How do I space the two component? I set the padding on all sides to 2dp already but they are still attaching to each other at the bottom, how do I space them? to 2dp. Comments are appreciated thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d8d8d8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0043"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="KELANA JAYA LINE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d8d8d8"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="74dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#001eff"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="TIME"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding is the space "inside" the view boundaries and it is not compulsory for Views to respect it, althought System View do it (at least most of them).

To separate two Views use layout_margin.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0043"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" >
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have change

```
android:padding="2dp"
```

by

```
android:layout_margin="2dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

try `margin(left,right,top,bottom)` attribute instead

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you are using a Linear layout and the padding is only for the components inside of the components.(The text inside in your case). Why don't you use a relative layout so that you can put your components wherever you want?